# how to match both https and http in matches (manifest.json)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

At the moment I've got it like this:

```json
"matches": ['https://google.com/*', 'http://google.com/*']
```

Is there any way to combine these 2 URLs into one allowing both https and http?

(Manifest V3)

Answer (score 2):

1. `*` is for both http and https.
2. The real address of `google.com` is `www.google.com` ([Chrome hides the `www` part](https://superuser.com/a/1498561) by default)
3. Use double quotes.

```json
"matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/match_patterns/ you could do:

```
"matches": ["*://google.com/*"]
```

Comment: ty, working now <3